# Why won't my Dell desktop computer boot with my usb properly?

Tags: boot, usb, dell

everytime I try to boot up with usb to try to install it comes up with a distorted ubuntu desktop with a thick black line going through it!

How do I make it work!

I just got the PC and I don't know the specs.

Dell Dimension 4600C

Thats all I got to work with...

Comment: http://www.cnet.com/products/dell-dimension-4600c/specs/ Are you trying to install Ubuntu or Lubuntu? With limited specs full Ubuntu may not work.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Please help us help you: go to the BIOS and look how much RAM, hard disk, ... your system has so we can give you an informed answer...  Now we're just guessing (@oldfred. **;-) :P** )

Comment: ok I am at the system setup screen now

Comment: in regards to oldfred, I am trying to install ubuntu.

Comment: It says Installed System Memory: 256MB DDR SDRAM

Comment: as for hard drive, the closet thing I could find was Drive Configuration... I don't know if that is correct or not.. As you can probably tell, I'm not much of a BIOS saavy person.

Answer (score 0):

Download the Ubuntu Minimal Cd. The file size is only less than 30MB.

[From here](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/mini.iso)

You won’t be able to create a Usb startup disk with this iso file, so the only way is to burn it into a bootable Cd.

Make sure your PC is connected to a LAN network. Insert the Cd into your Cd-Rom and boot up your computer from the Rom. Then select `Install`.

Select the language, follow by your location.

Let it detect your keyboard. Optionally, you can select `No`, you can select from a list of keyboard layout.

Next, the installer will proceed to configure some files for networking.

When it is done, it will prompt you to enter the hostname. This will be what you will see in the terminal later.

Select the mirror for Ubuntu archive that is closest to your location.

Unless you are using a proxy to connect to the outside world, leave the HTTP proxy field blank.

The installer will now retrieve the necessary packages from the mirror site.

Once it is done, it will prompt you to reformat your hard disk.
If you are going to use the whole hard disk,select `Guided – use entire disk.`

If not, you can select `Manual` and configure the partitioning accordingly. I suggest three partitions, one primary ext4 /, and two logical /home ext4 and swap.

When prompted, select `Yes` to confirm the partition setting.

Now, sit back and let the installer do its work.

Once it’s done, it will prompt you to enter your username, password and whether you want to encrypt your Home directory. I suggest not encrypt.

The installer do the final installation on your PC.

When prompted on how you want the security update to be done, select `Install Security Update Automatically`.

The next part is the important part. Here is where you can choose what to install on this machine. You want to choose what to install on this system, I suggest going to select `Xubuntu-desktop` or  `Ubuntu LXDE desktop`

The last thing it will install is the Grub loader. Select this if this is the only OS running in the machine and the Grub loader does not interfere with other bootloader.

Finally. this is what you will see when the installation is completed. Remove the Cd from the Cd-Rom and select `Continue` to restart the computer.

Comment: what are the differences between Xubuntu-desktop and Ubuntu LXDE desktop?

Comment: Just different light desktops

Comment: ok. I was having trouble burning the .iso to a dvd+r... I tried it last night and it gave me an error message. In Fact, brasero didn't even recognize my dvd... I'll try again today. btw, I'm not on my comp at the moment and I gotta go.